# Como Substituir barra e espaço por ponto e virgula no C#

Tags: c#, .net, string

Quero criar um sistema que remove todos barra e espaços por ponto e virgula, por exemplo

```
4587 / 5458 = 4587;5458 
4587 5458 = 4587;5458
```

Como posso fazer para criar esse sistema com C#?

Meu código até o momento está assim:

```
private void bt_validar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string hs = hs_codes.Text;
    string altera = hs.Replace("/", ";").Replace(" ", ";").Replace(".", ";").Replace(",", ";").Replace(" / ", ";");
    txt_alterado.ReadOnly = false;
    txt_alterado.Focus();

    txt_alterado.Text = altera;
}
```

Porém quando é informado numero com espaço e barra, o sistema coloca diversas vezes o ponto e virgula, por exemplo:

```
5787 / 5875 = 5787;;;5875
```

Comment: Coloque seu código e onde está tendo problema, e dados de teste.

Comment: Ficou melhor explicado?

Comment: Sim, apesar que você podia ter formatado direitinho, é só ver os ícone aí em cima da tela de edição.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certamente alguém virá com uma solução de RegEx, que em tese é melhor odo que está fazendo (gera várias alocações de memória sem necessidade e pressiona o GC), mas pra mim fazer na mão é imbatível.

Usei o [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para evitar múltiplas alocações. Eu converti para `ToString()` no final e ali no `WriteLine()` nem precisava porque ele faz automático, mas deixei porque no seu código precisará fazer a conversão.

A regra básica seria varrer toda a *string* e ir copiando cada caractere, poderia até usar LINQ, filtrando quando não for dígito e trocar pelo `;` (eu entendi que qualquer coisa que não seja dígito deveria converter, mas a pergunta não deixa isso tão claro). Até aí é fácil, o problema é que não pode repetir o `;` se ele já está presente. Então tem que montar uma máquina de estado.

Criei uma variável de controle que indica se o último caractere analisado é um dígito. Começo considerando que é.

Sempre que for dígito e o anterior não era um dígito deve concatenar o `;`, afinal se era um caractere irregular antes e agora vou começar colocar dígito, preciso marcar com o caractere especial escolhido. E obviamente que se é um dígito tenho que dizer que o atual é esse, pra no próximo passo o algoritmo saber o que fazer.

Quando não for um dígito é melhor fazer nada, afinal você tem que sumir com esse caractere, ele não pode ser mostrado. A única ação é identificar que agora não é um dígito na variável de controle.

O segredo é matar todo caractere inválido sem exceção, e antes que começar concatenar uma sequência de dígitos (pode até ser um único na sequência), colocar o caractere especial separador escolhido, mas nunca logo que começa.

Para criar uma máquina de estados tem que pensar como uma funcionaria. Que decisão tomar com cada caractere sendo analisada. É como um compilador funciona.

Se entendi a regra corretamente o código seria este (dá para encapsular em um método genérico:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Text;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var hs = "/4587 / 5458/";
        var texto = new StringBuilder(hs.Length);
        var digito = true;
        foreach (var chr in hs) {
            if (char.IsDigit(chr)) {
                if (!digito) texto.Append(';');
                texto.Append(chr);
                digito = true;
            } else digito = false;
        }
        WriteLine(texto.ToString());
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/x3c44O). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4bHvyh). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/BuildFiltered.cs).

Talvez dê para otimizar ainda mais com o novo [`Span<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), mas não vou arriscar essa complicação para você.

Comment: Po cara, me salvou muito obrigado, me salvou muito, arrumei umas coisas, mas me salvou de verdade, muito obrigado!!! Onde aprendeu tanto C#?

Comment: Uma nota sobre o Regex: ele é mais genérico e personalizável, em casos mais complexos, é mais fácil para o programador (mas não mais eficiente, claro), e a expressão pode ser inserida pelo usuário, essa conveniência que torna o uso do Regex preferencial em certos casos e não sua altíssima eficiência mecânica.